# Creating two related objects in one POST @onetomany

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have tow Entities Joined (University and Student) To post new student I send a json file to spring like this :

> **{"cne":132,
>        "universitymap":{existing university }}**

my problem : I don't want to post existing university with the student
i need to post new student with new university in the seem time!!

```js
@Entity
public class University {
 @Id
    
   @GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )  
   @Column(name = "id_university")
  private int id_university;
 
  @Column(name = "nom")
  private String nom;
 
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "univeersitymap",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Student> student;
   
    @getters & setters
 -------------------------------

@Entity
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )  
@Column(name = "id_student")
 private int id_student;

@Column(name = "cne")
private Date  cne;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="university_id")
private University universitymap;

@getters & setters
```

Comment: From an API perspective it would be better to create the university separately. If your post creates either one or two resources depending if one exists or not it is rather confusing and error prone

Comment: But if you really want to do that, you would need to find an existing university entity matching the posted details and if none is found create and save one then add the student.